# Java Ant XML Build Failed, Cause: The name is undefined

Tags: java, xml, ant

```
    <path id="checkstyle.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib/">
        <include name="checkstyle-6.12.1-all.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path> 

<target name="checkstyle">
        <!-- CheckStyle  -->
        <taskdef resource="checkstyle.properties" classpath="C:\Users\Pil\Desktop\Workspace2\Cs376bDemoApp\lib
             \checkstyle-6.12.1-all.jar" />
        <checkstyle config="DsrJavaFormattingProfile.xml" classpath="C:\Users\Pil\Desktop\Workspace2\Cs376bDemoApp\lib
             \checkstyle-6.12.1-all.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.java" />
    </target>
```

This is my checkstyle target in my build.xml file. I have spent the past 6 hours debugging this before resorting to StackOverFlow but my best efforts proved fruitless. I am consistently met with the error report [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource checkstyle.properties. It could not be found.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Pil\Desktop\Workspace2\Cs376bDemoApp\build.xml:86: 
Problem: failed to create task or type checkstyle
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

My intention for this code is for it to use my DsrJavaFormattingProfile.xml on  the .java files in my src directory. I have tried replacing the class path with the relative path "lib/" and with the checkstyle.classpath path above aswell as every possible other solution I could think of.

```
<taskdef resource="checkstyle.properties" classpathref="checkstyle.classpath" />
        <checkstyle config="DsrJavaFormattingProfile.xml" classpathref="checkstyle.classpath" />
```

also resulted in the same error. Please save me StackOverFlow, I need a hero.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBwS66EBUcY

Update: Solved by CAustin

`

```
<target name="checkinit">
        <path id="checkstyle.lib.path">
            <fileset dir="lib" includes="checkstyle8.8all.jar" />
        </path>
        <taskdef resource="com/puppycrawl/
tools/checkstyle/ant/checkstyle-ant-task.properties" classpathref="checkstyle.classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="checkstyle" depends="checkinit">
        <!-- CheckStyle  -->
        <checkstyle config="${basedir}\DsrCheckStyleConfig.xml" classpathref="checkstyle.lib.path">
            <path refid="project.sourcepath" />
            </checkstyle>
        </target>`
```

Comment: Your `taskdef` is pointing to "checkstyle.properties" which doesn't appear to be a file that exists in that jar. As the documentation points out, the task properties file is located at `com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/ant/checkstyle-ant-task.properties`. See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html

Comment: @CAustin `<taskdef resource="checkstyle.properties" classpath="com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/ant/checkstyle-ant-task.properties" />` Gives me the same error, so does removing that line entirely

Comment: That's the classpath, which you had correct originally. The properties file goes in the `resource` attribute.

Comment: @CAustin Thank you! Stupid mistakes, problem solved, you are truly a hero.